# React Material UI Table/Data Grid

Tags: reactjs

I have created a table using React Material UI and in one of the cell I have a dropdown and also rows are selectable using the checkbox. I am trying to access the rows that have been selected. Is there any sort of array that React Material UI creates to keep track of selected rows. If not how can I access selected rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the "Sorting and Selecting" section [here](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/), it shows an example that "tracks" the items you have currently selected. It has a `useState` call  `const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState([]);` which is setting selected items whenever you click a `TableRow`.

Comment: This is very useful as I am creating a Table in which I am want to select one or many rows and in one column of every row I want to have a dropdown and when the dropdown value is changed I want to send the update request to API if the row id is in the selected list.